# How to turn an array of an array of doubles into string, Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have an array of array of doubles. How do you convert that to a single string printed on the console?

I need to create a function that takes in an array of arrays of doubles as a parameter and returns a string object. Then loop through each of the inner arrays and concatenate each element of the inner arrays into a String object. But I'm not sure how to go about that.

```
var array1 = [2.6, 6.7, 7.2, 4.1, 3.1]
var array2 = [1.2, 3.5, 2.8, 4.5, 6.4]
var array3 = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]

var nestedArray = [array1, array2, array3]
```

This is the code I have... but i don't know how to do a for loop that would give me my answer...

```
func nestedFunction(nestedArray: [[Double]]) -> String {
    var stringVar: String = ""

    ( for loop here... )

    return stringVar
}

print(nestedArrayFunction(nestedArray))
```

The expected output should be a string object, with no brackets

Comment: Can you please show us the expected output?

Comment: Yeah I'm confused too. I need to create a function that takes in an array of arrays of doubles as a parameter and returns a string object. Then loop through each of the inner arrays and concatenate each element of the inner arrays into a String object. But I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: What's your expected output in the example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description in your question it seems as if the argument of `nestedFunction(...)` should be an *array of arrays with double valued elements* (`[[Double]]`) rather than an *array with double valued elements* (`[Double]`).

You can make use of `.flatten()` to your simply nested array `nestedArray` in `nestedFunction(...)`, and thereafter e.g. `reduce` to transform the `Double` valued elements of the flattened array to one concenated `String`.

```
var array1 = [2.6, 6.7, 7.2, 4.1, 3.1]
var array2 = [1.2, 3.5, 2.8, 4.5, 6.4]
var array3 = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]

var nestedArray = [array1, array2, array3]

func nestedFunction (nestedArray: [[Double]])-> String {
    return String(nestedArray
        .flatten()
        .reduce("") { $0 + ", " + String($1) }
        .characters.dropFirst(2))
}

let asString = nestedFunction(nestedArray)
    // asString = "2.6, 6.7, 7.2, 4.1, 3.1, 1.2, 3.5, 2.8, 4.5, 6.4, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6"
```

As an alternative, if you're set on using a `for` loop, you can use `for ... in` on the flattened array, e.g.:

```
var array1 = [2.6, 6.7, 7.2, 4.1, 3.1]
var array2 = [1.2, 3.5, 2.8, 4.5, 6.4]
var array3 = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]

var nestedArray = [array1, array2, array3]

func nestedFunction (nestedArray: [[Double]])-> String {
    var stringVar: String = ""
    var isFirstElement = true
    for elem in nestedArray.flatten() {
        stringVar += (isFirstElement ? "" : ", ") + String(elem)
        isFirstElement = false
    }
    return stringVar
}

let asString = nestedFunction(nestedArray)
    // asString = "2.6, 6.7, 7.2, 4.1, 3.1, 1.2, 3.5, 2.8, 4.5, 6.4, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6"
```

Note that due to limited floating point precision, some double values might end up with a "messy" `String` representation (e.g. `2.6` might end up as `2.6000000000000001`) when using the direct `String` initializer (`String($1)` and `String(elem)` above, in the first and second method, respectively). To redeem this you could set a fixed number of fraction digits for the `String` representation of your `Double` values, using the following `String` initializer:

```
String(format: "%.3f", myDoubleValue)
    /*             \
           number of fraction digits (3 here) */
```

E.g., replace `String($1)` and `String(elem)` in the methods above by `String(format: "%.3f", $1)` and `String(format: "%.3f", elem)`, respectively, for some number of fraction digits of your choice. The `Double` values will be rounded to the number of supplied fraction digits.

Comment: @VeronicaG happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it without the brackets:

```
let string = nestedArray.flatMap { (array) in
    array.flatMap { String($0) }.joinWithSeparator(",")
}.joinWithSeparator(",")
```

Output:

```
"2.6,6.7,7.2,4.1,3.1,1.2,3.5,2.8,4.5,6.4,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6"
```

Mind that using `,` as separator isn't localisation proof, and in French locale would result in a string like "2,6,6,7,7,2" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Array conforms to [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible), so you can just use its [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible/1539130-description) property:

```
nestedArray.description
```

output:

> [[2.6000000000000001, 6.7000000000000002, 7.2000000000000002, 4.0999999999999996, 3.1000000000000001], [1.2, 3.5, 2.7999999999999998, 4.5, 6.4000000000000004], [1.2, 1.3, 1.3999999999999999, 1.5, 1.6000000000000001]]

This is what the regular [`print`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541053-print) function uses to print such arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to concatenate, or combine, the arrays you have. You can do that simply by creating another array, like this;

```
let fullArray = array1 + array2 + array3
```

Next, you can print the full array,

```
print(fullArray)
```

Which would give you something like

```
[2.6000000000000001, 6.7000000000000002, 7.2000000000000002, 4.0999999999999996, 3.1000000000000001, 1.2, 3.5, 2.7999999999999998, 4.5, 6.4000000000000004]
```

or you can create a string representation of this array using the .joinWithSeparator(String: String) method, like so

```
let stringRepresentation = fullArray.joinWithSeparator(",")
print(stringRepresentation)
```

Hope this helps!

---